# Blocking storm when adding member to DB role

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I managed to cause a blocking storm on a busy system whilst mapping a new Windows login to a particular database. The login had to be mapped to several roles within the database and I used the following syntax for each:

`ALTER ROLE [MY_ROLE] ADD MEMBER [DOMAIN\MyLogin]`

I was surprised when my process threw an error because it was chosen as the victim as part of a deadlock when trying to acquire a Sch-M lock. Below is some info from the deadlock graph:

`<process id="process110c00150c8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="METADATA: database_id = 10 DATABASE_PRINCIPAL(principal_id = 24)" waittime="64777" ownerId="40941534120" transactionname="ADD/DROP ROLE MEMBER" lasttranstarted="2022-07-15T09:59:07.447" XDES="0x1d0143136a8" lockMode="Sch-M" schedulerid="37" kpid="14512" status="suspended" spid="5161" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2022-07-15T09:59:07.437" lastbatchcompleted="2022-07-15T09:59:07.433" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.433" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="SERVER1" hostpid="8816" loginname="DOMAIN\login" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="40941534120" currentdb="10" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">`

Full Deadlock graph - https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer/y2247746f

The login was successfully mapped to all but one role, so I'm just wondering if this behaviour is by design as I couldn't seem to replicate it for one of the built-in roles such as db_datareader.

Any insights to this would be much appreciated as now I'm considering that I should be careful as to when I execute this type of operation in the future.

Comment: Can you share the full anonymized deadlock XML?

Comment: Deadlock XML is pretty big so just trying to figure out how to share it.

Comment: GitHub gists are common for stuff like that.

Comment: Cool will take a look - thanks.

Comment: Full deadlock attached

Comment: Were the `ALTER` statements in a transaction?

Comment: I see `transactionname="implicit_transaction"` in there a bunch, which is the default for the `clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server"`. It can often lead to [unrelated-looking queries blocking each other](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/implicit-transactions-why-unrelated-queries-block-each-other/).

Comment: My process uses Export-DbaUser from dbatools for this, so it generates a script file for each DB which contains the ALTER statements for each role required. I guess when the script file is executed all the statements are within an implicit transaction. The role that had the issue has the most objects which are accessed the most frequently.

Comment: Is Row-Level Security enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% an answer, but here's the story

The crux of this deadlock is

```
<owner id="process30fe6395868" mode="Sch-S" />
</owner-list>
<waiter-list>
<waiter id="process110c00150c8" mode="Sch-M" requestType="wait" />
```

`process110c00150c8` is your ALTER ROLE statement, and it's waiting to get an exclusive lock on the principal, which apparently is treated as a Sch-M lock.  But it's waiting for `process30fe6395868` to release its Sch-S lock on this resource (the graph gives no indication of why all these sessions need an Sch-S lock on this principal).  All the other sessions are waiting behind `process110c00150c8`'s pending Sch-M lock, because this is a "high priority" wait, which is the default for Sch-M locks.

Anyway `process30fe6395868` should finish its statement quickly and release the lock, the ALTER ROLE can proceed, and then all the other sessions will be unblocked.  But `process30fe6395868` can't progress.  It's been waiting for 4796ms.  The deadlock graph shows it as a threadpool waiter.

```
<threadpool id="schedulerf291b0040">
<owner-list>
<owner id="process2f230b87c38" />
...
</owner-list>
<waiter-list>
<waiter id="process30fe6395868" />
```

And while I'm not really sure what that means, it suggests that it's resource-related.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis, David. I could see the details you highlighted in the deadlock but I was just more surprised with the fact that adding a user to a role requires a shema lock. Although given it is an ALTER statement maybe it makes sense. I'm assuming in most circumstances this type of operation would be very quick and any locks held momentary. Maybe in this case I was just a little unlucky with the resulting blocking storm. I'll try and see if I can find out what process30fe6395868 might have been.